# Query Account.Name in Opportunity SOQL

Tags: soql

The following SOQL gives Account.Name perfectly in workbench:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Opportunity
```

The same when used inside Apex:

```
for (Opportunity relatedOpp : [SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Opportunity]) {
            //System.debug(relatedOpp.Account.Name);
            //gives a NullPointerExp as the Account object is NULL
}
```

How do I alter the SOQL so as to get the Account Name in Apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing `relatedOpp.Account` would work fine when a Opportunity is linked to an Account and would give a null pointer exception when `AccountId` is null.

When accessing reference field in apex, always a best practice to perform a null check. Example below:

```
for (Opportunity relatedOpp : [SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Opportunity]) {
    if(relatedOpp.AccountId != null) {
        // System.debug(relatedOpp.Account.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even optimize your SOQL to filter opportunities have `AccountId` populated within query itself to avoid getting all records. Its a best practice that always put `WHERE` condition in your SOQL statements.

```
for(Opportunity relatedOpp :[SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId != NULL]){
    System.debug(relatedOpp.Account.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or where there is no contact role in an opportunity. I've also added a filter to a specific account Id.

```
SELECT Id, Name, account.name, (SELECT Contact.Name,Contact.Email, ContactId FROM OpportunityContactRoles) FROM Opportunity WHERE accountid='0018E00000VmZfDQAV' AND ContactId != NULL
```